# Scroll the page container of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm into an iframe, and I'd like to scroll (when I click on a link inside the iframe) the whole browser window on top. Can I do this?

I control either the page container and the iframe.

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var contents = $('iframe').contents(),
    element = contents.find('#click');

element.click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
});
```